# Making jquery Dialog working between two pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-dialog

I have a dialog setup as follow

```
$("#myDialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: true,
     close: function(event, ui) {
         $("#myDialog-content").html("");
         $(this).dialog("destroy");
     }
});
$("#myDialog").css("min-height","");
$("#myDialog-content").html("Loading...");
$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(response) { 
        $("#myDialog-content").html(response);
     }
});
```

This working fine I load and close dialog in same page but not able to make it work properly where I move between pages.

Here is a my page flow

1. From source page(say PageA) I make AJAX call to load the page containing dialog div(say PageB).
2. Link on this page call above method to display dialog. (For first time it runs OK).
3. When I click close button. Dialog close and with firebug I can still see dialog div at the end with UI classes but in hidden state.
4. If I go back to source page (Page A) and reload the PageB.In firebug I can see two div - one originally from JSP and second one from step 3.
5. Now if I click button to load dialog box - It used hidden to populate new data and never use new div created by jquery. So I just have blank dialog box.

I am not sure if this is jquery Dialog issue or my page flow. One possible solution I though of is use remove in close function to remove dialog div completely but it puts burden to create this div everytime page PageB is loaded. Is there any other way or any thing I am doing wrong in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly the situation, You have 2 options:

1. If you somehow cleaning the content of "Page B", remove the modal
   then.
2. If you do not have the cleaning mechanism like that, just
   `.remove()` content of modal on `close`

Sidenote: i would advise not to use jquery for `.css` and `.html('Loading...')`. Also, it is good to cache jquery elements in variables e.g `var dialog = $("#myDialog")`;

Comment: If I add .remove() as $(this).dialog("destroy").remove(); link doesn't open dialog when I click again. I had to reload the page again. I think its because it remove whole div and div is recreated/add only after page loded next time. Any other solution as I am not cleaniong whole PageB as mention in (Option 1).